# Forecasting monthly visitor count from daily values

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I have a dataset of the daily visitor count of a website. Given this information, I want to forecast what the monthly visitor count will be.

Depending on the visitor count on a day of the month, I would want to update the forecast for the monthly count.

Which method can I use to forecast the monthly number of visitors on a website using the same information on a daily level?

**EDIT**

I have data for six months at a day level. So for each day of the month, I have the daily unique visitor count and the total unique visitor count for each month.

This data is based on login data. I see how many unique logins are there for the day and that becomes the `Daily uniq visitors`.

I do the same process across a month to get `Monthly uniq visitors`

This is what the data looks like.
[image]

Comment: Umm...why not sum the numbers of visitors (predicted or actual, depending on what you have) over the days of the month?

Comment: I could add that up but that would lead to double counting of users visiting the webpage. I am looking for monthly *unique* users.

Comment: You haven't described any kind of data that would enable you to do that.

Comment: I have added it in the edit now. Please check.

Comment: You need information about repeat visitors. For instance, one person visiting your site each day for six months gives a series $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ of $183$ counts and $183$ distinct people visiting your site can give the same series of counts. Are you saying the monthly counts are of distinct visitors rather than totals?  That appears to be so, but offering a small example of your data could help.

Comment: I have added a snapshot and a little description of the data I have.

Comment: Thank you.  What does "monthly unique visitors" mean when it's associated with individual *days?*  Are you saying there's really just one value for the calendar month of July 2020? Or is this possibly a rolling or windowed statistic? (+1, by the way, because the nature of your question is now clear enough and I think it's a new one for this site.)

Comment: Monthly unique vistors: For a particular month, say July, I fetch data of the users that logged in at least once. From that pool, I see the distinct number of users for the month. That becomes monthly unique users. 

Yes, so for July there will be one value only because that is the truth value. I want to use the number of distinct transacting users for a given day to forecast what the monthly total will be.

Thanks!

Comment: I can make this a windowed statistic if a suggested method to forecast requires that kind of input. I have login and session info which I use to generate this table

Comment: It could get really interesting in that case if the windows overlap ;-).

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: That would provide more information than non-overlapping windows and would be more challenging (but potentially more rewarding) to analyze.